# error while starting phoenix application

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elm

Cloning a phoenix app and running locally gives below error on OSX 
https://github.com/stoft/mobbur

Tried removing _build, deps , node_modules and reinstalling twice but still the error comes regarding file watcher.

Is it currently not possible to use these with Node 6 ?

```
**elm -v** 

0.17.1

**elixir -v**

Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Elixir 1.3.2


**node -v**

v6.5.0

**npm -v**

3.10.3
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'lastIndex' of object '[object RegExp]'
  at RegExp.exec (native)
  at RegExp.test (native)
  at testCriteria (/Users/apple/Documents/app/test10/node_modules/anymatch/index.js:29:26)
  at Array.some (native)
  at anymatch (/Users/apple/Documents/app/test10/node_modules/anymatch/index.js:59:48)
  at FileList.isIgnored (/Users/apple/Documents/app/test10/node_modules/brunch/lib/fs_utils/file_list.js:66:16)
  at FileList._change (/Users/apple/Documents/app/test10/node_modules/brunch/lib/fs_utils/file_list.js:185:26)
  at emitMany (events.js:127:13)
  at FileList.emit (events.js:201:7)
  at BrunchWatcher.changeFileList (/Users/apple/Documents/app/test10/node_modules/brunch/lib/watch.js:227:19)
  at BrunchWatcher.startCompilation (/Users/apple/Documents/app/test10/node_modules/brunch/lib/watch.js:292:12)
  at FSWatcher.chokidar.watch.on.on.absPath (/Users/apple/Documents/app/test10/node_modules/brunch/lib/watch.js:166:14)
  at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
  at FSWatcher.emit (events.js:191:7)
  at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/Users/apple/Documents/app/test10/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:171:15)
  at FSWatcher._emit (/Users/apple/Documents/app/test10/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:212:5)
  at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/Users/apple/Documents/app/test10/node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js:288:12)
  at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/Users/apple/Documents/app/test10/node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js:335:7)
  at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
```

Comment: No idea, I'm running node v5.8.0 and npm v3.7.3, guess I won't upgrade until this has been clarified... ;)

Comment: Had the same issue on node v6.6.0. Rolled back to v5.9.0 using `brew uninstall node && brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/37ede1a116b215fcfe5a2a8d9a376d0ba43b873b/Formula/node.rb` and the issue has been resolved. You may be asked to rebuild some modules after the rollback